# Mixing default and named imports changes how code works

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Sometimes I see imports like this `import React, { PropTypes} from 'react'` and it doesn't cause any problems.

But when I try to do this in my code `import Router, { hashHistory } from 'react-router'` my render call doesn't render anything.

When I change it to `import { Router, hashHistory } from 'react-router'` then it works.

What's the rule here? When can I import with and without `{}` in same import statement and when I can't? Looking into `react-router` code it does export `Router` as defult.

Comment: It is [unlikely](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/index.js) that it exports it as default. If `RouterDefault` were defined and equal to `Router` in `import RouterDefault, { Router }` it wouldn't be possible to see the behaviour you're describing, would it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import without `{}` when a module defines a `export default`

`react-router` doesn't have any `export default`.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/index.js

```
export Router from './Router'
export Link from './Link'
export IndexLink from './IndexLink'
export withRouter from './withRouter'

/* components (configuration) */
export IndexRedirect from './IndexRedirect'
export IndexRoute from './IndexRoute'
export Redirect from './Redirect'
export Route from './Route'

/* utils */
export { createRoutes } from './RouteUtils'
export RouterContext from './RouterContext'
export { locationShape, routerShape } from './PropTypes'
export match from './match'
export useRouterHistory from './useRouterHistory'
export { formatPattern } from './PatternUtils'
export applyRouterMiddleware from './applyRouterMiddleware'

/* histories */
export browserHistory from './browserHistory'
export hashHistory from './hashHistory'
export createMemoryHistory from './createMemoryHistory'
```

Maybe you were looking into the code of an old version of `react-router` which used to have an `export default`

[Version 1.0.x](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/1.0.x/modules/index.js)

```
/* components */
export Router from './Router'
export Link from './Link'
export IndexLink from './IndexLink'

/* components (configuration) */
export IndexRedirect from './IndexRedirect'
export IndexRoute from './IndexRoute'
export Redirect from './Redirect'
export Route from './Route'

/* mixins */
export History from './History'
export Lifecycle from './Lifecycle'
export RouteContext from './RouteContext'

/* utils */
export useRoutes from './useRoutes'
export { createRoutes } from './RouteUtils'
export RoutingContext from './RoutingContext'
export PropTypes from './PropTypes'
export match from './match'

export default from './Router'
```

Comment: I checked node_modules\react-router\lib\Router and node_modules\react-router\es\Router. Is it not the place to check? I'm just starting with es6 and node.

Comment: the file which contains all the exports is `node_modules\react-router\lib\index`